# How to auto run the Active X Controls in Html Files

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, web-applications

While using IE, its always asking me to start the active X controls. Is there any method or way to activate the Active X controls.

Answer (score 3):

If you're asking about the warning when loading local files, then all you have to do is add the following comment after your page doctype:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->
```

Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<!-- saved from url=(0014)about:internet -->

<html>
<head>
<title></title>
```

Comment: sounds like a little security hole

Comment: oops, sorry, i forgot that you're talking about just local files. nevermind.

Comment: I am asking about active X control

Comment: Note that the file must be saved using Windows-style CRLF line endings (at least on the first line) for this ugly “mark of the web” scheme to work.

Answer (score 0):

For company intranet computers, you can change settings under Internet settings > Security > Trusted Sites. Add the site to the trusted sites, select Custom Level and enable ActiveX. Note that there is a difference between signed and unsigned ActiveXs, so you may want to get is signed. You'll have to distribute these settings to all users, something a system guy should know how to do.
If you're on the internet, however, you probably don't want to use ActiveX.