# Need a Windows exe file to launch a html page in local drive without ActiveX warning

Tags: html, windows, internet-explorer

I need to distribute a flash-based application to end users. I have a very simple index page to launch another window:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
function popUp(URL, w, h) {
win=window.open(URL,"window","menubar=no,width=" + w + ",height=" + h + ",toolbar=no,resizable=no;titlebar=no");
self.close();
}
</script>
<BODY onLoad="javascript:popUp('flash.html', 1024, 768)">
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

And the flash-only page is like

```
<html>
<head><title>Applet<title></head>
<body>
 <object width="1024" height="768">
 <param name="movie" value="somefilename.swf">
 <embed src="somefilename.swf" width="1024" height="768">
 </embed>
 </object>
</body>
</html>
```

This flash application has fixed dimension: 1024x768 and it is embedded in a non-resizable browser window.

I create a desktop icon for the starting page and end-users can double-click this icon to start the application.  After the ActiveX warnings, the flash application can start nicely and everythin work fine.

The problems I need to resolve are:
(1) The starting page does not closed by itself automatically (it will ask whether you want to close it or not).
(2) ActiveX warning. As I think it is normal, but end-users do not think so.

Is any Windows executable file can start a fix-size IE browser with content in local harddrive ?

Answer (score 1):

bobince has the right tool, but links to an answer with the wrong argument.
You actually need `<!-- saved from url=(0016)http://localhost -->`. (See also [my earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721446/721519#721519).)

Answer (score 0):

Include the [Mark of the Web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634337/how-to-auto-run-the-active-x-controls-in-html-files) in the HTML to allow script and plugin content on IE.

Use [window.resizeTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536723%28VS.85%29.aspx) to change the size of the current window rather than attempting to open a new one and close the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the advice of using MOTW. It works in certain way that I can launch a local html file without ActiveX warning.  However, I need to open a non-resizable menu-less browser to start my swf application.

I found a solution for my case...I change this html page to a HTA application (change the file extension from html to hta, add some hta-specific syntax).  End-users can start the application by double-click start.hta and it just looks like a normal Window application to them.